# Code block text coloring not working?

Tags: support

So Sometimes my code will highlight properly and other times, it gets no colors or anything. What gives! I can't find anything on this meta that has discussed this aspect of this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called [syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) as explained over in the SE-meta post :

> Before you do anything, are you sure that you've got the correct
>   highlighting turned on? Behind the scenes, **Stack Exchanges uses the
>   tags on the question to infer the language** you are using. If there's
>   more than one tag that has syntax highlighting, it uses a default and
>   lets Prettify infer what's the best language to use. If you're curious
>   whether a tag has a language hint, any user is capable of checking by
>   visiting that tag's wiki page.

Bolding mine. So, if you're offering a code answer to a question that isn't tagged with the code, you won't get syntax highlighting by default.

You can force a specific syntax by using Prettify language codes. Put this immediately before a code block, and it'll be highlighted as Bash:

```
<!-- language: bash -->

    for f in *.mp3; do echo "$f"; done
```

Comment: @slhck I tried that with `lang-vb` but I'm thinking I wasn't clear on exactly where it should be. In the code? Outside the code?

Comment: Outside the code, before the code block. See for example here: http://superuser.com/posts/885595/edit